# SQL in ArcGIS - Find value LIKE in multiple columns

Tags: sql, where-clause, arcgis, sql-like, or-operator

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1 and it only allows you to write out the WHERE statement to filter certain features from a table.

My current statement is:

```
COLUMN1 LIKE '%value%' OR COLUMN2 LIKE '%value%'
```

Basically I have to get all rows that have a certain word in the strings in either column 1 or 2. I'd combine the columns but they only support 254 characters each and I need more than that.

Is it possible to search more than one row in each statement without using multiple OR operators?

Comment: Does your current query...not work? Throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

I confess this is a bit of a stab in the dark, but you might be able to combine the contents of the two columns into a single string to be compared like this:

`COLUMN1 + COLUMN2 LIKE '%value%'`

Certainly this is valid SQL for SQL server so may work for ArcGIS too.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I fear that it's not actually SQL being used but just the interpretation. No surprise there since Arc is generally a piece of trash.